# How can convert hex to int using go

Tags: go

I converting hex value to decimal using go using below mentioned code

```
numberStr := strings.Replace(s, "0x", "", -1)
    numberStr = strings.Replace(numberStr, "0X", "", -1)
    n, err := strconv.ParseUint(numberStr, 16, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return n
```

Hexa value is : `0x340aad21b3b700000`

but thrown error : `strconv.ParseUint: parsing "340aad21b3b700000": value out of range`

Can you suggest any alternate solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maximum value for uint64 is 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF, thus to use overflowing value you have to resort to package math/big of the standard library:

```
import "math/big"

...

n := new(big.Int)
n.SetString(numberStr, 16)
```

Continue with the package [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big).

Comment: Note: if you want to pass a string prefixed by "0x", you need to pass base 0 instead of 16; in that case golang will pick the base itself based on the prefix. 

If however one passes both a 0x-prefixed string and an explicit base of 16, golang will produce the value 0.